# How to use a file in AWK as a 'reference' to another

Tags: text, awk

I have file1 which is like this, with XLOC going from 1 - ~20 000

```
XLOC_013407 black   0.7015504883
XLOC_014674 black   -0.6747375792
XLOC_018639 black   -0.654810098
XLOC_014606 black   -0.6262770784
XLOC_015975 black   -0.6242929154
```

and file2 which is like this, but a small subset of the first file, but without the colour values

```
XLOC_000509
XLOC_000556
XLOC_000657
XLOC_018639 
XLOC_005521
XLOC_005129
XLOC_001253
```

I would like to use file2 as a reference, to print the corresponding values in column 1 and column 2 of the file1 to produce an output

Like

```
XLOC_018639 black
```

I know rudimentary AWK and this is the pseudocode I think I need

```
awk 'if $1 (from file2) == $1 (from file1) {print $1,$2 (from file1)}'  > outfile.txt
```

Obviously this won't work as it is above - could someone help me on turning it into proper code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention that `file2` is small, you would write:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{print $1, $2}' file2 file1
```

With `NR==FNR` we compare the total record index with the current file record index, so the first block is executed for the first file only (`file2`). Since  we used `next`, we skip the remaining script, so the other block is executed only for the second file (`file1`)

Comment: Right and **if** efficiency is an issue (really shouldn't be with such small files) then since the $1 values seem to be sequentially growing you could add an exit once the $1 value from file1 is larger than the last $1 from file2: `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];max=$1;next} $1>max{exit} $1 in a{print $1, $2}' file2 file1`